# phpmyadmin export database #1064 error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I exported a database with phpmyadmin, but when I want to import it in the same server I got the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '<!DOCTYPE HTML><html lang='en' dir='ltr'><meta charset="utf-8" /><meta name="rob' at line 1
```

The is the beginning of my sql file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html lang='en' dir='ltr'><meta charset="utf-8" /><meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" /><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"><link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" /><link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="phpmyadmin.css.php?server=1&amp;token=02d653d1677ee4aab118dc2a5613c576&amp;nocache=5510312691ltr" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./themes/pmahomme/jquery/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" /><title>localhost:8080 / 127.0.0.1 / careersearchdb / table 1 | phpMyAdmin 4.0.4.1</title><script type='text/javascript' src='js/get_scripts.js.php?scripts[]=jquery/jquery-1.8.3.js&scripts[]=ajax.js&scripts[]=keyhandler.js&scripts[]=jquery/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js&scripts[]=jquery/jquery.sprintf.js&scripts[]=jquery/jquery.cookie.js&scripts[]=jquery/jquery.mousewheel.js&scripts[]=jquery/jquery.event.drag-2.2.js&scripts[]=jquery/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js&scripts[]=jquery/jquery.ba-hashchange-1.3.js&scripts[]=jquery/jquery.debounce-1.0.5.js&scripts[]=jquery/jquery.menuResizer-1.0.js&scripts[]=rte.js&scripts[]=functions.js&scripts[]=navigation.js&scripts[]=indexes.js&scripts[]=common.js&scripts[]=codemirror/lib/codemirror.js&scripts[]=codemirror/mode/mysql/mysql.js'></script><script type='text/javascript' src='js/messages.php?lang=en&amp;db=careersearchdb&amp;server=0&amp;token=02d653d1677ee4aab118dc2a5613c576'></script><script type='text/javascript' src='js/get_image.js.php?theme=pmahomme'></script><script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
PMA_commonParams.setAll({common_query:"server=0&token=02d653d1677ee4aab118dc2a5613c576",opendb_url:"db_structure.php",safari_browser:"0",querywindow_height:"400",querywindow_width:"600",collation_connection:"utf8_general_ci",lang:"en",server:"0",table:"table 1",db:"careersearchdb",token:"02d653d1677ee4aab118dc2a5613c576",text_dir:"ltr",pma_absolute_uri:"http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/",pma_text_default_tab:"Browse",pma_text_left_default_tab:"Structure",confirm:"1"});
AJAX.scriptHandler.add("jquery/jquery-1.8.3.js",0).add("ajax.js",0).add("keyhandler.js",1).add("jquery/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js",0).add("jquery/jquery.sprintf.js",0).add("jquery/jquery.cookie.js",0).add("jquery/jquery.mousewheel.js",0).add("jquery/jquery.event.drag-2.2.js",0).add("jquery/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js",0).add("jquery/jquery.ba-hashchange-1.3.js",0).add("jquery/jquery.debounce-1.0.5.js",0).add("jquery/jquery.menuResizer-1.0.js",0).add("rte.js",1).add("messages.php?lang=en&amp;db=careersearchdb&amp;server=0&amp;token=02d653d1677ee4aab118dc2a5613c576",0).add("get_image.js.php?theme=pmahomme",0).add("functions.js",1).add("navigation.js",0).add("indexes.js",1).add("common.js",1).add("codemirror/lib/codemirror.js",0).add("codemirror/mode/mysql/mysql.js",0);
$(function() {AJAX.fireOnload("keyhandler.js");AJAX.fireOnload("rte.js");AJAX.fireOnload("functions.js");AJAX.fireOnload("indexes.js");AJAX.fireOnload("common.js");});
// ]]></script></head><body><div id="pma_navigation"><div id="pma_navigation_resizer"></div><div id="pma_navigation_collapser"></div><div id="pma_navigation_content"><a class="hide navigation_url" href="navigation.php?ajax_request=1&amp;token=02d653d1677ee4aab118dc2a5613c576"></a><!-- LOGO START --><div id="pmalogo">    <a href="index.php?token=02d653d1677ee4aab118dc2a5613c576"><img src="./themes/pmahomme/img/logo_left.png" alt="phpMyAdmin" id="imgpmalogo" /></a></div><!-- LOGO END --><!-- LINKS START --><div id="leftframelinks"><a href="index.php?token=02d653d1677ee4aab118dc2a5613c576" title="Home"><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="Home" alt="Home" class="icon ic_b_home" /></a><a href="querywindow.php?db=careersearchdb&amp;table=table+1&amp;token=02d653d1677ee4aab118dc2a5613c576&amp;no_js=true" id="pma_open_querywindow" class="disableAjax" title="Query window"><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="Query window" alt="Query window" class="icon ic_b_selboard" /></a><a href="./doc/html/index.html" target="documentation" title="phpMyAdmin documentation"><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="phpMyAdmin documentation" alt="phpMyAdmin documentation" class="icon ic_b_docs" /></a><a href="./url.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.mysql.com%2Fdoc%2Frefman%2F5.5%2Fen%2Findex.html&amp;token=02d653d1677ee4aab118dc2a5613c576" target="mysql_doc"><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="Documentation" alt="Documentation" class="icon ic_b_sqlhelp" /></a><a href="#" id="pma_navigation_reload" title="Reload navigation frame"><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="Reload navigation frame" alt="Reload navigation frame" class="icon ic_s_reload" /></a></div><!-- LINKS ENDS --><!-- RECENT START --><div id="recentTableList"><form method="post" action="sql.php"><input type="hidden" name="db" value="" /><input type="hidden" name="table" value="" /><input type="hidden" name="server" value="1" /><input type="hidden" name="token" value="02d653d1677ee4aab118dc2a5613c576" /><select name="selected_recent_table" id="recentTable"><option value="">(Recent tables) ...</option><option value="{&quot;db&quot;:&quot;careersearchdb&quot;,&quot;table&quot;:&quot;table 1&quot;}">`careersearchdb`.`table 1`</option><option value="{&quot;db&quot;:&quot;careersearchdb&quot;,&quot;table&quot;:&quot;table 2&quot;}">`careersearchdb`.`table 2`</option><option value="{&quot;db&quot;:&quot;careersearchdb&quot;,&quot;table&quot;:&quot;careersearchtb&quot;}">`careersearchdb`.`careersearchtb`</option><option value="{&quot;db&quot;:&quot;test&quot;,&quot;table&quot;:&quot;table 4&quot;}">`test`.`table 4`</option><option value="{&quot;db&quot;:&quot;test&quot;,&quot;table&quot;:&quot;nume2&quot;}">`test`.`nume2`</option><option value="{&quot;db&quot;:&quot;test&quot;,&quot;table&quot;:&quot;numetb&quot;}">`test`.`numetb`</option><option value="{&quot;db&quot;:&quot;test&quot;,&quot;table&quot;:&quot;numeTB&quot;}">`test`.`numeTB`</option><option value="{&quot;db&quot;:&quot;test&quot;,&quot;table&quot;:&quot;nume&quot;}">`test`.`nume`</option><option value="{&quot;db&quot;:&quot;careersearchdb&quot;,&quot;table&quot;:&quot;careersearchTB&quot;}">`careersearchdb`.`careersearchTB`</option><option value="{&quot;db&quot;:&quot;careersearchdb&quot;,&quot;table&quot;:&quot;test&quot;}">`careersearchdb`.`test`</option></select></form></div><!-- RECENT END --><img src="./themes/pmahomme/img/ajax_clock_small.gif" title="Loading" alt="Loading" style="visibility: hidden;" class="throbber" /><div id="pma_navigation_tree" class="list_container highlight"><div><ul></ul></div></div></div></div><noscript><div class="error"><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="" alt="" class="icon ic_s_error" /> Javascript must be enabled past this point</div></noscript><div id='floating_menubar'></div><div id='serverinfo'><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="" alt="" class="icon ic_s_host item" /><a href="index.php?token=02d653d1677ee4aab118dc2a5613c576" class="item">127.0.0.1</a><span class='separator item'>&nbsp;»</span><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="" alt="" class="icon ic_s_db item" /><a href="db_structure.php?db=careersearchdb&amp;token=02d653d1677ee4aab118dc2a5613c576" class="item">careersearchdb</a><span class='separator item'>&nbsp;»</span><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="" alt="" class="icon ic_s_tbl item" /><a href="sql.php?db=careersearchdb&amp;table=table+1&amp;token=02d653d1677ee4aab118dc2a5613c576" class="item">table&nbsp;1</a><div class="clearfloat"></div></div><div id="topmenucontainer" class="menucontainer"><ul id="topmenu"  class="resizable-menu"><li><a class="tab" href="sql.php?db=careersearchdb&amp;table=table+1&amp;token=02d653d1677ee4aab118dc2a5613c576&amp;pos=0" ><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="Browse" alt="Browse" class="icon ic_b_browse" /> Browse</a></li><li><a class="tab" href="tbl_structure.php?db=careersearchdb&amp;table=table+1&amp;token=02d653d1677ee4aab118dc2a5613c576" ><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="Structure" alt="Structure" class="icon ic_b_props" /> Structure</a></li><li><a class="tab" href="tbl_sql.php?db=careersearchdb&amp;table=table+1&amp;token=02d653d1677ee4aab118dc2a5613c576" ><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="SQL" alt="SQL" class="icon ic_b_sql" /> SQL</a></li><li><a class="tab" href="tbl_select.php?db=careersearchdb&amp;table=table+1&amp;token=02d653d1677ee4aab118dc2a5613c576" ><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="Search" alt="Search" class="icon ic_b_search" /> Search</a></li><li><a class="tab" href="tbl_change.php?db=careersearchdb&amp;table=table+1&amp;token=02d653d1677ee4aab118dc2a5613c576" ><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="Insert" alt="Insert" class="icon ic_b_insrow" /> Insert</a></li><li><a class="tab" href="tbl_export.php?db=careersearchdb&amp;table=table+1&amp;token=02d653d1677ee4aab118dc2a5613c576&amp;single_table=true" ><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="Export" alt="Export" class="icon ic_b_tblexport" /> Export</a></li><li><a class="tab" href="tbl_import.php?db=careersearchdb&amp;table=table+1&amp;token=02d653d1677ee4aab118dc2a5613c576" ><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="Import" alt="Import" class="icon ic_b_tblimport" /> Import</a></li><li><a class="tab" href="tbl_operations.php?db=careersearchdb&amp;table=table+1&amp;token=02d653d1677ee4aab118dc2a5613c576" ><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="Operations" alt="Operations" class="icon ic_b_tblops" /> Operations</a></li><li><a class="tab" href="tbl_tracking.php?db=careersearchdb&amp;table=table+1&amp;token=02d653d1677ee4aab118dc2a5613c576" ><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="Tracking" alt="Tracking" class="icon ic_eye" /> Tracking</a></li></ul>
<div class="clearfloat"></div></div>
<a id="goto_pagetop" href="#" title="Click on the bar to scroll to top of page"><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="" alt="" class="icon ic_s_top" /></a><div id="page_content"><a class="hide" id="update_recent_tables" href="index.php?ajax_request=1&amp;recent_table=1&amp;token=02d653d1677ee4aab118dc2a5613c576"></a>-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.0.4.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Mar 01, 2014 at 02:35 PM
-- Server version: 5.5.32
-- PHP Version: 5.4.19

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
```

Comment: Do you need all that html?

Comment: remove the html tags and import it again

Comment: Seems like your dump has been fetched from a buggy web page.

Comment: I removed the html tags and worked. Thank you very much